# Blink a shape in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'd like to blink out a texture in an android live wallpaper.  I can easily just not draw that shape for a second, but I'd like it to look more realistic.

How can I blink (like an eye blink) a shape.  I'd like it to progressively close.  One idea was to have another duplicate shape with a fragment shader that only covered a percentage of the shape on each iteration of draw, but I'm not sure how to determine if the pixel should be transparent or not from within the shader.  Any ideas?

Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think the best way would be to not draw it for few frames and then draw it again. If you hide it for just one frame that would be too fast if your fps is high, so you need to make sure the object is hidden for atlas 0.2 seconds for the eye to register it as a blink

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. But I want it to appear to blink, so gradually clip it out of the view, not draw it for half a second more, and then gradually open it again.

Comment: Why not scale it down and back again? if you want it to animate

Comment: I'm just learning opengl. That's the sort of info I'm looking for. I'll try scaling the matrix before drawing. I haven't worked with scale yet. So far I've only rotated and translated. Thanks, I'll try that tonight.